# no visible @interface for x declares the selector initwithnib:bundle

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, bundle, viewcontroller

```
#import "levelSelectorController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
ViewController *viewController;

@interface levelSelectorController ()

@end

@implementation levelSelectorController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        // iOS 7
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    } else {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES     withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
}

@end
```

The error occurs here:

```
viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

I have tried a few different things i read on stackoverflow and i understand what the error is supposed to mean. But i still can't manage to solve the problem.

Comment: The code is `initWithNibName`

Comment: @Fogmeister i don't understand what you are trying to tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector. It is:

```
viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```